# List of events that are getting fired in the DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, logging, browser

Is there any way i could get a list of events that have been fired in the DOM? I don't want to trace by adding breakpoints.

Am looking for something like an internal browser log with the order of the events being fired for the page that is being loaded. This should include all events, even the likes of mouseup, mousedown.

Comment: This question has been answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/446892/how-to-find-event-listeners-on-a-dom-node

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're on chrome, you can also install an extension called "Visual Event" works pretty good to me, and it list all DOM events.

[Link to chrome web store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/visual-event/pbmmieigblcbldgdokdjpioljjninaim)

Answer (score 0):

Firebug offers a "log events" option that shows all DOM events being fired inside an element (can be used on body element).

Just inspect the HTML, right click on an element and click Log Events (tested on Firefox)

Comment: Thank you. does safari have any such option? PS. that is a hilarious typo

Comment: I supose Firebug Lite (the one that can be installed on Safari/Chrome) should also offer this tool, but im not sure, only have Firebug installed on Firefox.

Comment: Chrome has chrome://user-actions/ chrome://net-internals/